# Docker build: returned a non-zero code: 1, when test is failed

Tags: docker, selenium, dockerfile, pytest

When I run Docker build with my  project Docker+Selenium+Pytest in Jenkins CI with tests that end with the SUСCESS status - the build is pushed and the results are published to reports, and if at least one test fails - the build fails and the results are not published

Build Error: `The command 'pytest test_page.py -s -v --alluredir=reports/allure-results' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Maybe my instructions for Docker are incorrectly configured.
My DockerFile

```
FROM python:latest  as python3
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
USER root
WORKDIR /my-projest
ADD . /my-projest
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --user -r requirements.txt
RUN sudo pip3 install pytest
RUN ["pytest", "test_page.py", "-s", "-v", "--alluredir=reports/allure-results"]
```

and SHELL Command

```
echo "Build docker image and run container"
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
docker run -d --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME

echo "Copy allure-results into Jenkins container"
rm -rf reports; mkdir reports;

docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:my-project/reports/allure-results reports
```

Comment: You're `RUN`ning the tests as part of the image build.  You probably want it to be the `CMD` that runs as the main container process instead.  (It probably still will exit with code 1 for failure, though your script doesn't check that.)

Comment: then maybe it is worth remaking the RUN command on the SMD 
CMD ["pytest", "test_page.py", "-s", "-v", "--alluredir", "reports/allure-results"] 
So?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your tests are failing on an assertion and that failed assertion may be throwing the non 0 error code.

[this link outlines the expected exit codes for each scenario](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/exit-codes.html)

```
Exit code 0
All tests were collected and passed successfully

Exit code 1
Tests were collected and run but some of the tests failed

Exit code 2
Test execution was interrupted by the user

Exit code 3
Internal error happened while executing tests

Exit code 4
pytest command line usage error

Exit code 5
No tests were collected
```

Comment: and how can this be solved? add the line exit 0, or can I add some commands to the docker to push and publish the results to the report?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when testcases are failing docker build is exiting with non-zero code.

One way around to generate report even when testcases are failed

```
echo "Build docker image and run container"
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .


echo "Copy allure-results into Jenkins container"
rm -rf reports
docker create -it --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:my-project/reports/allure-results ./reports
docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME
```

You can user report copy part in Jenkins pipeline in post stage under always block, so that whether build pass or fail you can always get reports.

Comment: Unfortunately does not help, did everything the same way. Maybe I should do the Jenkins Pipeline as you pointed out

Comment: If you are using in Jenkins pipeline, Post stage block is only solution, as once Stage gives failure, Jenkins will mark stage fail and no next command will execute.

Comment: "RUN pytest test_page.py -s -v --alluredir=reports/allure-results || true", can you try update dockerfile for RUN cmd as this? It might help but not recommended.

Comment: bin/sh: 1: pytest test_page.py -s -v  --alluredir=reports/allure-results || true: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c "pytest /test_page.py -s -v  --alluredir=reports/allure-results || true"' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Sorry than I think Post stage is only solution

Comment: I  created JenkinsFile and published in https://pastebin.com/AmvHW5Nb , I stumbled upon the same error again